# Pass complex value to templateParameters collection in Devops Pipeline Run API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using the Azure Devops Pipeline Run API documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). It works fine except that it does not seem to support passing complex objects via the `templateParameters` in the request body.

E.g.

```
parameters: 
- name: myObject
  type: object
  default:
  - val1
```

Call the api with this request body:

```
{
  "resources": {
    "repositories": {
      "self": {
        "refName": "refs/heads/main"
      }
    }
  },
  "templateParameters": {
    "myObject": [
      "val2"
    ]
  }
}
```

The pipeline runs with `myObject` set to the default `val1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body should be like this:

```
{
  "resources": {
    "repositories": {
      "self": {
        "refName": "refs/heads/main"
      }
    }
  },
  "templateParameters": {
    "myObject": "- val2"
  }
}
```

Results of `- powershell: Write-Host "${{ parameters.myObject[0] }}"`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shayki, what would the templateParameters look like if the object looked like this:         "extra_tags": {
            "1": "one",
            "2": "two"
        }

Answer (score 1):

With pipeline parameter like :

```
parameters: 
- name: myObject
  type: object
  default:
  - val1
- name: myObject2
  type: object
  default:
  - Name: toto
    Value: tata
  - Name: toto2
    Value: tata2
```

You should use :

```
$RunPipelineBody = @{
  "templateParameters" = @{
    "myObject" = "- val1new"
    "myObject2" = "- Name: totonew`n  Value: tatanew`n- Name: toto2new`n  Value: tata2new"
  }
}
```

And

```
-Body $( $RunPipelineBody | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 10 -Compress)
```