# devops api run pipline with multiple parameters

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a pipline with two parameters that i want to run using devops-api.

It seems only one parameter is accepted.

#--------- my powershell request ----------

```
$body = @"
{
    "templateparameters": "{
        \"environmentconnection\":\"avd-d-lab-p\"}",
        \"avdtype\": \"OntwikkelLow\"
    }",
    "definition": {
        "id": 96
    },
}
"@


Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.0" -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json" -body $body
```

#------- Pipline Yaml ----------

```
parameters:
  - name: environmentconnection
    displayName: Select your destination
    type: string
    default: avd-d-lab-n
    values: 
    - avd-d-lab-n
    - avd-d-lab-p
    - avd-n-dev
    - avd-p-prod
  - name: avdtype
    type: string
    displayName: Select your AVD type
    values:
    - OntwikkelLow
    - OntwikkelMedium
    - OntwikkelHigh
    - TestLow
    - TestMedium
    - TestHigh
```

#-------- Pipline details ------

```
_links   : @{self=; web=}
url      : https://dev.azure.com/{project}/15c1d992-70ab-4790-9650-04cd457af10b/_apis/pipelines/96?revision=2
id       : 96
revision : 2
name     : 3. AVD Create Sessionhost Keuzemenu
folder   : \AVD
```

#------- error---------

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 5837e9f7-e6ca-4a3f-bff9-7a34ad2a20dc.","typeName":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException, 
Newtonsoft.Json","typeKey":"JsonReaderException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project} ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Pass complex value to templateParameters collection in Devops Pipeline Run API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666372/pass-complex-value-to-templateparameters-collection-in-devops-pipeline-run-api)

Now using:

```
    $body = @"
    {
        "templateParameters":{
            "environmentconnection":"avd-d-lab-p",
            "avdtype":"OntwikkelLow"
        }
    }
    "@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/96/runs?&api-version=7.0" -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json" -body $body
```

or

```
$RunPipelineBody = @{
  "templateParameters" = @{
    "environmentconnection" = "avd-d-lab-p"
    "avdtype" = "OntwikkelLow"
  }
}
$body = $( $RunPipelineBody | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 10 -Compress)
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/96/runs?&api-version=7.0" -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -ContentType "application/json" -body $body
```